# How to edit Context() before it gets rendered? Django

Tags: python, django

Processor from TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is not allowed to edit context or I'm confuse?
Even if i subclass

```
class MyContext(Context):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Context.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Context and try to pass it to context_instance it does not gives me acces to dictionary. It is appends it right before render.

```
return render_to_response(template, {'hello':'Hello World'}, context_instance=MyContext())
```

So how do I analyze and edit contexts before it gets rendered?

**UPDATE:**

The only way i found is to subclass Context end overwrite update method.

```
class RequestContext(Context):

    def update(self,other_dict):
        print other_dict
        super(RequestContext, self).update(other_dict)
```

Comment: I wanna make decorator which allows you to edit content right in page without without help of admin. So you just decorate you model and it alway will be editable in you website if you have permission to do that. I wanted to use http://aloha-editor.org/. It would be a plaggble app. But in case if there is not way to edit context it wont be as pluggable as I wanted it to be. I just need to wrap fields by divs

Answer (score 0):

You can just set same variable name and it will overwrite it, check Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). You cannot read context inside context processor. You could probably use [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), but they're not really meant for that.